# Implementing a LinkedList in Python - Is leetcode wrong?

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm working on this problem: https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/linked-list/209/singly-linked-list/1290/

and leetcode is telling me that my code is throwing a runtime error. The input it's trying to make my code run is this:

```
["MyLinkedList","addAtHead","deleteAtIndex","addAtHead","addAtHead","addAtHead","addAtHead","addAtHead","addAtTail","get","deleteAtIndex","deleteAtIndex"]
[[],[2],[1],[2],[7],[3],[2],[5],[5],[5],[6],[4]]
```

Where the first array contains the function name and the second contains the function parameters. E.g. the second element adds a 2 at the head of the linkedlist. My question is that how would it be OK to be deleting the element at index 1 when there is only one element in the linkedlist? Is there some special thing about linked lists that I should know or is the input case incorrect. Below is my code for reference.

```py
class SinglyLinkedList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.length = 0
    
    def get(self, index):
        if index<0 or index>self.length: raise AssertionError("get index must be in bounds")

        node = self.head
        for _ in range(index):
            node = node.next
        return node
    
    def addAtHead(self, val):
        node = SinglyListNode(val)
        if self.length==0:
            self.head = node
            self.tail = self.head
        else:
            node.next = self.head
            self.head = node
        self.length+=1
    
    def addAtTail(self, val):
        node = SinglyListNode(val)
        if self.length==0:
            self.tail = node
            self.head = self.tail
        else:
            self.tail.next = node
            self.tail = node
        self.length+=1
    
    def addAtIndex(self, index, val):
        if index<0 or index>self.length:
            raise AssertionError(f"index at which to add ({index}) is out of bounds")
        
        if index==0:
            return self.addAtHead(val)
        if index==self.length:
            return self.addAtTail(val)

        newNode = SinglyListNode(val)

        node = self.head
        for _ in range(index-1):
            node = node.next
        newNode.next = node.next
        node.next = newNode

        self.length+=1

    
    def deleteAtIndex(self, index):
        if index<0 or index>self.length:
            raise AssertionError(f"index at which to add ({index}) is out of bounds")
        
        if index==0:
            self.head = self.head.next
        elif index==self.length-1:
            self.tail=self.get(self.length-2)
        else:
            node = self.head
            for _ in range(index-1):
                node = node.next
            node.next = node.next.next
        self.length-=1

    
    def __str__(self):
        res = "["
        node = self.head
        for _ in range(self.length-1):
            res += str(node)+","
            node = node.next
        res += str(node)+f"] ({self.length})"
        return res
```

Comment: Is it possible they are counting from 1 instead of 0?

Comment: I guess that could be the case. Poor testcase IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://leetcode.com/problems/design-linked-list/

> `void deleteAtIndex(int index)` Delete the `index`<sup>th</sup> node in the linked list, **if the index is valid.**

Looks like the delete needs to be done only when the index is valid. Your code needs to handle the case when the index is invalid.